# Should the "Distracted" modifier be applied to Vigor rolls made to avoid Bleeding Out?

Tags: conditions, savage-worlds, savage-worlds-adventure-edition

I want to know if the Distracted modifier should be applied to Vigor rolls made to avoid Bleeding Out.

The rules state that the Distracted modifier applies to all trait rolls.

Personally, I don't feel that it would make sense, because you are already down and practically out of combat to be an opponent.

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: @Szega Interpreted this question as "The question is not whether you can be Distracted while bleeding out, but whether it should have any effect on your survival". Is that an accurate summary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, But ...

Let's look at the relevant rules. (Highlighting added.)

> DISTRACTED: The hero subtracts 2 from all Trait rolls **until the end** of his next turn.

And

> Bleeding Out: The injured character is dying and must make a Vigor roll **at the start of** his turn. Failure means he perishes. With success he survives but must roll again next turn (or every minute if not in combat). With a raise, he stabilizes and no further rolls are required.

(It is worth noting that if Distracted is caused by some situational rules, notably Grappling, then the end condition changes drastically. But that is mostly irrelevant to the main question, so I won't mention that again.)

If a character is Distracted and they end up Bleeding Out then the Distracted penalty *still applies* for that *first* roll. The Bleeding Out roll happens *at the start* of the next turn, while Distracted doesn't expire until *the end* of the next turn. ***However***, if the character manages to survive that first Bleeding Out roll then Distracted goes away.

Other relevant rules:

- Allies can stabilize the character with a simple (TN 4) Healing roll, as an Action, on their own turns.
- The character is still dealt Action Cards. Partly to determine turn order, and when in the round the character bleeds, but also because they still get the full benefits of a Joker. Including the +2 to all Trait rolls.
- Successful magical *healing* also automatically stabilizes the character and removes the Incapacitation caused by Wounds.

### But "should it really?"

That is a subjective question, one that each table needs to answer for themselves. If the table agrees that it should not apply then the GM rules that Distracted ends with Incapacitation and that's that.

As for the narrative logic of applying the penalty, it's simple to describe the character lying in a pool of their own blood, forlornly trying to hold in their guts, their broken will too feeble to cling to life long enough for their body to stabilize. That narrative would definitely apply Distracted.

Comment: re:last part; The question is not whether you can be Distracted while bleeding out, but whether it should have any effect on your survival. I would rather explain it with "as you were Distracted, you got hit in a worse place than otherwise". Although that brings up the question of *applying* Distracted to such a character...

Comment: @Szega If that is the actual question then this needs to be closed. That's purely opinion and taste, not a question of rules, and therefore outside the scope of RPGSE.

Comment: My question was about the application of the _Distracted_ modifier should be applied as stated by the official rules. House rules are always subject to the decision of the group.